# Preventing duplicate storage to realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using realm to store and persist my data. Everything works fine and I just discovered that users can actually store duplicate item which is bad. I would am unable to create a check to prevent duplicate items, any help would be appreciated

**Function**

```
func addData(object: OfflineModel)   {    
    try! database.write {
        database.add(object, update: true)
    }
}

//MARK:- Get Offline
func getDataFromDB() -> Results<OfflineModel> {
    offlineItems = database.objects(OfflineModel.self)
    return offlineItems!
}

//MARK:- Create Offline
func createOfflineList(createdDate: Date, photo: Data, title: String, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {        
    REALM_QUEUE.sync {        
        let offlineList = OfflineModel()

        offlineList.createdDate = createdDate
        offlineList.photo = photo
        offlineList.title = title
        OfflineFunctions.instance.addData(object: offlineList)
        completion(true, nil)
    }    
}
```

**Model**

```
@objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
@objc dynamic var photo: Data? = nil
@objc dynamic var title : String = ""
@objc dynamic var createdDate: Date?

override static func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "id"
}
```

Comment: I assume you can store duplicate items because you are setting a random UUID as an ID

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the `createOfflineList` method you create a new `OfflineModel`, which generates a random `id` using `UUID().uuidString` and hence you cannot have duplicate models from Realm's point of view, since `id`, which is used as the primary key will always be different. You'll need to use `title` (or any other non-random property that you actually want to use to identify your model instances) as the primary key.

```
class OfflineModel: Object {
    @objc dynamic var photo: Data? = nil
    @objc dynamic var title : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdDate: Date?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "title"
    }
}
```

Comment: I would rather suggest `createdDate` to be opted as a primary key as it will be unique. `title` can be repeated and may not be unique.

Comment: @hardikparmar the whole point is to not let the user add several objects that seem to be different due to their unique primary key but in reality represent the same thing. Several models with the same title but created at different points in time don't seem to be different from the users point of view.